# TypeScript class extends JavaScript function

Tags: typescript

I wanted to create a new `class` extending from an existing class-like JavaScript `function`

```
function MyFunctionClass() { }

MyFunctionClass.prototype.myMethod = function(str) {
  console.log(str);
};
```

I wrote this simple piece of code

```
class Test extends MyFunctionClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

let t = new Test();
t.myMethod('Test');
```

And surprisingly it does work, as it prints `Test` and no runtime errors are raised.
However, the TypeScript playground tells me

> Type '() => void' is not a constructor function type.

Can I safely ignore this error and use that code in production?

Comment: You can do so, but create a javascript file to store that function and a declaration file to declare the function as class, then typescript will not throw error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do that, you'd create a TypeScript declaration file (`mumble.d.ts`) to provide TypeScript with the information about the class, for instance:

```
// In a .d.ts file associated with the project
declare class MyFunctionClass {
  myMethod(str: string): void;
}
```

That way, not only does TypeScript know that `MyFunctionClass` is a class, it also knows that `myMethod` expects a string and doesn't have a return value.

> And surprisingly it does work...

It's not surprising. :-) Remember that TypeScript compiles to JavaScript. If you're targeting ES5, TypeScript's `class` construct compiles to a JavaScript constructor function and associated prototype, which TypeScript can hook up in an inheritance relationship with the JavaScript `MyFunctionClass`. If you're targeting ES2015+, TypeScript's `class` compiles to a ES2015+ `class`, and ES2015+ `class` can use an ES5-style constructor function in the `extends` clause.

Comment: what should be tsconfig? I do this but still I get error

Comment: @canbax - If the `numble.d.ts` file is alongside your other `.ts` files, in my experience it just gets picked up. That's described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include). [This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#what-is-a-project-reference) may also be useful. So I think you just need to make sure that TypeScript is including the `.d.ts` file.